# Не работают "сырые сокеты"

Tags: c++, сокеты

Добрый вечер. У меня громадная проблема, не знаю как ее решить: Нужно сделать лабу-генератор tcp пакетов. В виндовс, как я понял, всё это дело прикрыли... Нашел WinCap... Говорят хорошая вещь... Можно ли с помощью этого WinCap'a сформировать "руками пакет" и отправить в сеть? Искал в сети исходники отправки пакетов с помощью винкапа-ничего не нашел... А вот снифферов хоть отбавляй( У кого-нибудь есть исходники или вообще просто ссылки, может попадались, по отправке tcp пакетов?

Comment: А не проще поговорить с преподавателем? pcap вообще-то -- interface for user-level packet capture.

Comment: Если не получится то так и придется сделать... Но я уже не одну неделю убил на эти пакеты... Как-то обидно, что нет никакого результата... Т.е. в виндовс эти raw сокеты не будут работать? Неужели нет способа заставить их работать? Я и XP SP1, 2 , 3 ставил и 2000-ю... Везде проблемы какие-то...

Comment: @Alerr, а в Linux-е почему нельзя? 

В конце-концов можно поставит VirtualBox (например) в Windows и запустить Linux в нем.

Comment: В принципе можно, я так и сделал... WmVare->Ubuntu... Но я не силен в линуксе и это программирование не в windows... Попробовал скомпилировать код, который нашел в сети, как результат получил ошибку что-то наподобии у вас нет прав-operation not permitted... Что это значит?

Comment: @Alerr такие же проблемы Вы должны были получить и под виндами, если нормально работаете. Посмотрите, какие привилегии нужны для raw-sockets. Но если Вы там по умолчанию `Администратор` и около того, тогда Вы этого и не заметите.

Comment: посмотрите исходники hping3 (линукс правда), но с pcap вроде совместим

Comment: @Alerr, в \*nix raw-сокеты доступны только root. 

Соответственно при отладке sudo bash, и вперед.

Для готовых программ, которые должны вызываться обычным юзером надо сделать владельцем root-а и установить **s** бит.

Comment: @avp `sudo bash` мне понравилось. Я, по простоте душевной, всегда пользовался `su`.

Comment: Так как стать админом? я писал $su свой_логин, зетем свой пароль... Ничего не изменилось.. Как от root запустить программу?

Comment: @Alerr `sudo Ваша-программа`, если с настройками всё в порядке. Или просто `su`, что то же самое, что `su root`